# Android studio DDMS not showing file explorer

Tags: android, ddms

I'm not sure if i'm missing something or am having an issue.
Whenever i pull up ddms on my app it shows the device but the file explorer and every other tool shows up blank

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWNbm.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS1sh.png)